# Making tags favorite in mobile versions of SE sites

Tags: feature-request, tags, mobile-web, tag-watching, bookmarks

Now I'm not able to make tags favorite in mobile versions of all Stack Exchange sites. Maybe I just haven't found how but in this case UX should be improved and be more intuitive.

If open a Desktop version on mobile it's also impossible to make a tag favorite because there is no popup with a star like in desktop browsers on mouse hover.

For example, a star toggler may be placed here:

[image: Favorite tags toggle proposal]

Answer (score 1):

There is alternative way to mark tags as favorites, which will work in full site version even on mobile as it doesn't require hovering.

1. Go to the desired site homepage, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/
2. See the "Favorite Tags" section in right sidebar, and click/tap "edit:

   > [image]
3. Type the tag you want to favorite, and click/tap "Add":

   > [image]

That's it, the result is the same as if you clicked the star while hovering.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Haven't find this before.